# Syntax error for query that excludes NULL values

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run the below code but keep getting

> Run Time Error 3075 syntax error in query expression: CCC In (686200, 681400) And [Previous Scope] Not Is Null

The code is

```
DB.CreateQueryDef queryName, "SELECT * FROM HRCC WHERE CCC In (" & costCentres & ") And   [Previous Scope] " & IIf(newStaff, "Is Null", "Not Is Null")
```

Answer (score 2):

`... [Previous Scope] NOT IS NULL` is indeed incorrect syntax.

The correct syntax would be `... [Previous Scope] IS NOT NULL`.